# 2.2.6 - Email address is now required. Why?

Tags: email, magento2.2.6, customer-attribute

Create New Order -> Create New Customer -> Email field is now required.

Why has this been implemented and why is it not noted on the Release Notes for 2.2.6? How do I make it a non-required field again.

I was told on the magento2 github that this is expected behavior.

My response: It was not required in 2.2.5. I don't understand why the change has not been documented. Please point me to a commit or discussion that explains the reason for this change. Or why this is not a feature you can turn on/off. Not everyone in the world has email addresses or sometimes they prefer not to give it out. Now we have to try and makeup a different dummy address every time because if it matches another email the order will not be created.

The email address has never been a required field even going back to magento1

Thanks!

** ***EDIT*** **

[image]

[image]

Comment: The email address has always been a required field for a customer and order. How would you login without an email?

Comment: explain the 2 screenshots then, and go back to any version prior to 2.2.6 including Magento1. Never been required until 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

From Magento 2.2.6 onwards email is a required field.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22251

It should be optional. There should be a configuration option for this.